# Como executar uma ação sempre que o $uibModal for fechado?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Como faço para executar uma ação sempre que o `$uibModal` for fechado?

Apenas para facilitar o meu aprendizado, quando eu fechar o modal, quero exibir uma mensagem.

Por exemplo:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TesteController', function ($scope, $uibModal) {

     $scope.modal = function () {

          var modal = $uibModal.open({
             template: '<div class="modal-body">Olá mundo</div>'
          });

          // Como posso executar isso?

          modal.quandoFechar(function () {
            $scope.mensagem = 'Você fechou o modal';
          });
     };
})
```

A função `modal.quandoFechar` obviamente não existe, mas eu quero saber se existe alguma função que execute um callback quando o `$uibModalInstance` for fechado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar alguma ação com o "resultado" da modal, você precisa usar a promisse `result` e a função `then`.

Todas funções **`then`** podem receber até três callbacks

- **`successCallback`** é executado quando a promisse é resolvida;
- **`errorCallback`** é executado quando a promisse é rejeitada;
- **`notifyCallback`** é executado quando notificado.

Sempre que ocorrer um clique fora da área da modal (no background) irá resultar numa promisse rejeitada.

Exemplo:

```
modal.result.then(function () {
    $scope.mensagem = 'Você fechou o modal';
}, function () {
   $scope.mensagem = 'Clique fora da modal';
});
```

Se você quiser mostrar a mesma mensagem pra ambos os casos, ou até mesmo, executar alguma ação após a exeção do callback passado para o **`then`**, é possível usar a função **`finally`**

```
modal.result.then(function () {
    $scope.mensagem = 'Promisse resolvida';
}, function () {
   $scope.mensagem = 'Promisse rejeitada';
})
.finally(function(){
    $scope.mensagem2 = 'Modal fechada';
});
```

Comment: No meu caso, eu preferi usar o `finally`, pois eu estava "limpando os dados" ao fechar a modal. Daí independente se for "dismiss" ou "close", ele executa o que tá no `finally`.